# How to add a Cisco AnyConnect VPN profile on linux?

Tags: linux, vpn, cisco-anyconnect

I'm runing linux mint and have Cisco AnyConnect VPN  client (v 4.6.01098) working with my primary VPN connection.

I need to add a second VPN profile, but all the instructions I can find suggest that you just type the VPN domain name into the `Connect to:` field of the AnyConnect client, but in my client that text box is not ediable (I can put my cursor there, and mark text, but not edit).

Is anyone familiar with Cisco AnyConnect and how to add another VPN profile to it?

Answer (score 0):

You should install the NetworkManager OpenConnect plugins:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-openconnect 
sudo apt install network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```